# DOCKER error: Pull access denied for coffeeteareadb, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a `Spring` `MVC` application that I want to add to `Docker`. I created the `image`, configured `Docker`, but the application in `Docker` does not want to start. In the application I use `Spring Boot` and `PostgresSQL` database.

*Dockerfile*:

```java
FROM openjdk:11
ADD build/libs/Coffeetearea-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar Coffeetearea-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
#EXPOSE 8080:8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "Coffeetearea-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

*docker-compose.yml*:

```java
version: '3.1'
services:
  app:
    container_name: coffeetearea
    image: coffeeteareaimage
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - coffeeteareadb
  coffeeteareadb:
    image: coffeeteareadb
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass123
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=coffeetearea
```

*application.propeerties*:

```java
#Databse
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://coffeeteareadb:5432/coffeetearea
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=pass123
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

MY STEPS in TERMINAL:

```java
C:\Users\vartanyan\IdeaProjects\Coffeetearea>docker-compose up
Creating network "coffeetearea_default" with the default driver
Pulling coffeeteareadb (coffeeteareadb:)...
ERROR: The image for the service you're trying to recreate has been removed. If you continue, volume data could be lost. Consider backing up your data before continuing.

Continue with the new image? [yN] y
Pulling coffeeteareadb (coffeeteareadb:)...
ERROR: pull access denied for coffeeteareadb, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Comment: For the database container, do you mean to use a standard image, like `image: postgres:13`?

Comment: how can i watch it? that's all I have, I haven't added / wrote anything else

Answer (score 1):

The error means that Docker cannot find an image named `coffeeteareadb` locally or on https://hub.docker.com/ . If your image is in private repository (meaning that someone in your party have already created it) you have to login Docker into that repository first. Although for private repository you image name should look like an URL: `registry.example.com/image-name:tag`.

If you want `coffeeteareadb` to be a regular PostgreSQL database, you probably want to change the `image` here:

```yaml
  coffeeteareadb:
    image: postgres:13  # https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres
```

If you are new to Docker, an `image` is like an executable or binary file, while a `container` is something like a running process of that executable. An `image` consists of several incremental layers of data: an application, dependencies, some basic config, etc. When you run an image you create a `container`. A container is an instance of an image. It differs from the image in the way that apart from just application, it has some information on how to run it (which ports to map, which volumes to mount, etc). There can be many containers using the same image. So when you asked to select an image you basically need to tell what application you want to use. Docker will look for it locally and on the hub, download it, and create a container from it. If you want to create your own image, you need a Dockerfile (see this reference https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/ ).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your image (coffeeteareadb) doesn't exist on dockerhub, so docker can't pull it.
Build it locally like coffeeteareaimage(build: buildpath).
Or use an PostgreSQL image that is on dockerhub (image: postgresql:latest).